# LIKE on multiple values, all must match

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm querying a legacy Oracle db to match a name using LIKE. It would be good if a multi-word pattern (could be 1 word, 3 words, 8 words, whatever) could be matched against names independently of word order. Eg, if the user searched for `"rob jon"`, it would match

```
ROBERT JONES
JONATHON ADAM PROBE
```

but not match

```
ROB SMITH
PETER JONES
```

If the requirement was "at least one word should match" I could use `REGEXP_LIKE(name, 'rob|jon", 'i')`.
But I can't work out how to make it match only when ALL words are found somewhere in the name. I could do this using Oracle Text, but I can't use that in this db. I also can't easily store the words in a table to join to either.

The query is currently static and uses bind variables, and so I would prefer not to add an extra LIKE predicate for each word in the search pattern.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According to your question and the data presented in the post, I Used this table

```
create table name_pattern 
(
    name_1 varchar(200)
);
```

insert statements :

```
insert into name_pattern 
select ( 'ROBERT JONES') from dual union all 
select ('JONATHON ADAM PROBE') from dual union all
select  ('ROB SMITH') from dual union all
select  ('PETER JONES') from dual;
commit;
```

try this if it works for you if you are searching "rob" and "jon" separately.

```
select name from table_name where lower(name) like '%rob%' and lower(name) like '%jon%' ;
```

try this if you want to search "rob jon" combined and to get your expected result

```
select * from name_pattern where REGEXP_COUNT(name_1, 'rob|jon',1, 'i') =2;
```

Comment: The second query doesn't work in all cases.  It will incorrectly return names such as `Rob Robertson` and incorrectly miss names such as `Rob Robin Jones`.

Comment: @Luke Woodward, yes with this data it's evident second query put wrong results, i will try to change it if possible.

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion, I should have been clearer - the user could enter multiple words, not just 1 or 2, and I would like to handle any number of words without generating the query dynamically (I want to use bind variables and not parse the query each time a query it submitted). Should I update the original question to make this clearer?

Comment: Thanks, have edited my question. And thanks for the second query, that was a good idea, though as Luke Woodward said, will not work as expected in certain cases.

Answer (score 2):

You want your query to accept one bind variable containing a blank-separated list of name parts, e.g. 'rob jon'.

You can write a recursive query to get the single name parts from that string. Then use `NOT EXISTS` to only keep names for which not exists any mismatch.

```
with parameters as
(
  select :namepartlist as namepartlist from dual
)
, nameparts (namepart, namepartlist, occurrence) as
(
  select regexp_substr(namepartlist, '[^ ]+', 1, 1), namepartlist, 1
  from parameters
  union all
  select regexp_substr(namepartlist, '[^ ]+', 1, occurrence + 1), namepartlist, occurrence + 1
  from nameparts
  where regexp_substr(namepartlist, '[^ ]+', 1, occurrence + 1) is not null
)
select * 
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select null
  from nameparts
  where lower(mytable.name) not like '%' || lower(nameparts.namepart) || '%'
)
order by name;
```

You can replace

```
  where lower(mytable.name) not like '%' || lower(nameparts.namepart) || '%'
```

by

```
  where not regexp_like(mytable.name, nameparts.namepart, 'i')
```

if you like that better.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e48caaa20e9397afe65516504c62acd

Comment: I did not expect that to work, but it does. Clever to implement multiple ANDs by turning it upside down and looking for a single non-match instead.

Answer (score 2):

*if* you prefer not to add an extra LIKE predicate for each word in the search pattern (the best solution IMHO) you can create a PL/SQL function to do the matching

```
FUNCTION PATTERN_MATCHES(pattern in varchar2, name in varchar2) returns number
is
Begin *pseudocode*
  *convert pattern to lowercase*
  *split pattern by spaces*
  *for each part, Loop*
     if NOT lower(name) like %part% then 
        return 0; --early exit
     end;
  End Loop;
  return 1; --all parts have a match
end;

select * from employee where PATTERN_MATCHES(:pattern, name)=1
```

Then you can have a static parameterized query.
On the bright side, you'll be able to extend the behavior (add advanced search for example) without touching the front-end app.

PS: The function code is intentionally left for you to write. Ask if you need help with that.

PS2: returning "number" and not a boolean will help you with legacy database drivers. Feel free to use integer or a boolean if that works for you.

Comment: I consider it a good idea to use PL/SQL for this. While it is possible to solve this with SQL (as shown in my answer), a PL/SQL function will be much more readable and easily expandable. I don't expect a great difference in runtime either.

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessy building on @Jfrd's solution ... is this any good ? (Performance will be shocking on large tables).

Basically, replace all spaces with '%' (not catered here for successive spaces).

```
var search_text varchar2(30)

exec :search_text := 'Rob Jon';

select name
from table_name
where lower(name) like REPLACE('%' || :search_text || '%', ' ', '%' ) ;
```

Comment: No, that would only match names that have "rob" and "jon" appearing in that order.